# Tensorflow - Fully connected neural network with single input neuron

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, tensor

I have 1D data batch tensor that has shape of `[batch_size, 500]`
The default fully connected neural network given by TF or Slim takes into account input layer of size 500. I want to have a share fully connected for all the 500 entries, but the model learns from single input and output neurons, as in the following picture:
[image]

Afterwards. all the outputs should be concatenated and has the same shape of `[batch_size, 500]`.

Comment: Your question is quite unclear; plus, a single neuron as in your scheme can be used only for a *scalar* input (i.e. of shape `(batch_size, 1)`), and not for a 1D array of `(batch_size, 500)` as you describe...

Comment: Thanks for your comment. This is exactly what I'm trying to do... create partition of all the vector so I can use single neuron for all the vector enteries.